# ckeditor config autolink_urlRegex does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using `ckeditor` (version `4.11.2`) in my angular app. I want to be able to automatically change a string to link when I'm pasting string like for example `file://link_to_local_file`.

I know that there is a `autolink` plugin. And there is also config option `autolink_urlRegex`. But when I'm changing this property in config object, it does not work:

```
autolink_urlRegex: /^(https?|ftp|file):\/\/(-\.)?([^\s\/?\.#]+\.?)+(\/[^\s]*)?[^\s\.,]$/i,
```

Also when I'm for example change this regexp to:

```
autolink_urlRegex: /^(https?):\/\/(-\.)?([^\s\/?\.#]+\.?)+(\/[^\s]*)?[^\s\.,]$/i,
```

It still works for `ftp://` links. I can change this regexp in `plugin.js` file but I dont want to.

Why this config option is not working?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an issue in the autolink plugin: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/3156

The plugin uses `CKEDITOR.config.autolink_urlRegex` instead of `editor.config.autolink_urlRegex` in 3 below places:

- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/autolink/plugin.js#L128
- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/autolink/plugin.js#L103
- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/autolink/plugin.js#L127

what makes it impossible to overwrite values for these properties.

I would recommend that you download autolink plugin and modify these 3 places so that they use `editor.config` instead of `CKEditor.config`. You can also download whole editor in [source version](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_source.html), make these changes and then [build editor from source](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_build.html).

**NOTE:** When checking the file URL, I have noticed it is `file:///C:/Users/someUser/Desktop/text.txt` and not `file://C:/Users/john/Desktop/DANE.txt` (notice 3 slashes after `file:`) so adding just a simple file to the start of the regex won't work. You will have modify it more.

Comment: The issue is already fixed in 4.14.1 version: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/pull/3930